# Ocaml : How can i install Mpqf Module?

Tags: ocaml

I would like to know how to install the module Mpqf in Ocaml.
Because when i try to use it, i get "Error: Unbound module Mpqf".
I'm on Ubuntu.

Thanks you.
(sorry for my English...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've installed OCaml through the Ubuntu package manager the module is located in the `libapron-ocaml-dev` package.

```
nlucaroni@rothko:~$ apt-file list libapron-ocaml-dev | grep mpqf
libapron-ocaml-dev: /usr/lib/ocaml/apron/mpqf.cmi
libapron-ocaml-dev: /usr/lib/ocaml/apron/mpqf.cmx
libapron-ocaml-dev: /usr/lib/ocaml/apron/mpqf.mli
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) ! I have already installed libapron-ocaml-dev package. I just checked, mpqf.cmi, mpqf.cmx and mpqf.mli are in the correct folder (/usr/lib/ocaml/apron/). But when i tried to compile "ocamlbuild exemple.byte" i get "Error: Unbound module Mpqf". So how should i compile it ?

Comment: It's helpful if you include the command you're using to attempt compiling. This will work in simple cases, `ocamlopt -I (path-to-mpfq) mpfg.cmx test.ml -o test`.